# How to add prefix to `join_through` table in `many_to_many` `assoc` at the Repo.*() level?

Tags: ecto

I'm trying query a `many_to_many` relationship with a prefix as follows:

```
Student
|> join(:left, [s], t in assoc(s, :teachers))
|> Repo.all(prefix: "my_prefix")
```

which results in a PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT s0."id", s0."name", s0."inserted_at", s0."updated_at"
FROM "my_prefix"."students" AS s0
LEFT OUTER JOIN "teachers_students" AS t2 ON t2."student_id" = s0."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "my_prefix"."teachers" AS t1 ON t2."teacher_id" = t1."id"
```

I would expect the prefix to get added to the `join_through` table `teacher_students`, but it doesn't get added. Is this a bug in Ecto? Or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was able to fix the problem by changing the `join_through` value in the `many_to_many` definition from a string to a module name:

```
schema "students" do
  # many_to_many :teachers, Teacher, join_through: "teachers_students", on_replace: :delete
  many_to_many :teachers, Teacher, join_through: TeachersStudents, on_replace: :delete
  ...
end
```

```
defmodule MyApp.TeachersStudents do
  use Ecto.Schema
  alias MyApp.Teachers.Teacher
  alias MyApp.Students.Student

  schema "teachers_students" do
    belongs_to :teacher, Teacher
    belongs_to :student, Student
  end
end
```

Ecto ignoring the prefix for the string value may be a bug.